# How language data is sent to the view file in OpenCart 3?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I have no idea how it works in new version in open cart . Previosly all language data   directly filled into controller array $data pass into view file , but now in controller just load a language file and I can't understand how data from language file send to template file . Help please

Comment: Hello Kolya, what language data are you trying to manipulate? I haven't seen a significant change in how the controller works so the language file is loaded as normal and each variable gets the data that is assigned which is stored in the $data array that you mentioned. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCart 3, the language variables are auto loaded into the controller. You don't need to declare the variables by yourself.

So you can add a new variable into the language file (catalog or admin) and then use it directly from your twig view.